# Instantiate to a specific position in Swift xCode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swipe, instantiation

I'm looking for some help.

I'm doing a homework for school on xCode and I have an issue.
I'm trying to ma multiple magazine cover that the user can scroll through them. I created a UIScrollview that I instantiate each .xib files (Magazine covers) in it but they stack on top of each other.

What I am actually trying to do is to instantiate the covers side by side (so the user can swipe through them like snapchat's filter). Is there a way to set a certain position?!?

SPECS OF THE PROJECT:

-I'm on the latest xCode beta.
-The target is an iPad Pro on iOS 10.3

Comment: Check out `UICollectionView` and its layout. Probably that is what you are looking for. It is a subclass of `UIScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

I believe UICollectionView is what you're looking for.
Try with this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started). It doesn't show exactly what you need but once you see how collection views work you'll realize how to implement your task (or come again for more questions :))